# How to handle Threads

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me

I am downloading a set of images. So I have a static class with a static method, which I use to start the new main thread. In the main thread, I have created new worker threads which download images for me which happens in the run method of the main thread. After worker thread finishes its task, it is deleted.

After some times, I am navigating to some other page in my application, which calls the same static method, the same process again. I am adding the request to vector queue in this main thread class, but the run method already got finished.

How do I make it run again?

Is this the correct way of approaching threads?

Static Method for a static class

```
public class ImageLoader {
    private static Vector requestQueue = new Vector();  
    static ImageDownloader  mThread ;   

    public static void loadImage(String url,ImageDownloadListener _listner){         
         CustomWorkerThread thread = new CustomWorkerThread(url, _listner);
         if(mThread==null){
             mThread = new ImageDownloader();
             if(!mThread.isAlive()){
                 mThread.start();
               }

        }
         ImageDownloader.loadImageThread(thread);
    }   
    public static void closeThreads(){
        ImageDownloader.stopAllThreads();
    }
}
```

Main Thread class

```
public static ImageDownloadListener listner;

static ImageDownloader mainThread;

ImageDownloader(){
    mainThread = this;
    this.start();       
}

public void run(){
    System.out.println("Within the Run Method Of Main Thread size>>>>>"+requestQueue.size());   
    while (true) {
        if(_stop)
            return ;
        if(requestQueue.size()>1){          
            while(count<2){
                CustomWorkerThread threader = (CustomWorkerThread)requestQueue.elementAt(0);
                requestinProgressQueue.addElement(threader);
                Thread th = new Thread(threader);
                th.start();
                count++;
                requestQueue.removeElementAt(0);
            }
        }else{
            //mainThread.run();
            synchronized (requestQueue) {
                try {
                    requestQueue.wait(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}   

public static void loadImageThread(CustomWorkerThread thread){
    System.out.println("Simple Counter>>>"+simplecount);
    synchronized (requestQueue) {
            requestQueue.addElement(thread);
            requestQueue.notify();
    }

    simplecount++;          
}

public synchronized void stop(){        
    _stop = true;               
}

public  static void Reload(){
    if(requestQueue.size()>=1){         
        while(count<2){
            CustomWorkerThread threader = (CustomWorkerThread)requestQueue.elementAt(0);
            requestinProgressQueue.addElement(threader);
            Thread th = new Thread(threader);
            th.start();
            count++;
            requestQueue.removeElementAt(0);
        }
    }

}

public synchronized static void stopAllThreads(){
    if(requestQueue.size()>=1){
        for(int i=0;i<requestinProgressQueue.size();i++){
            CustomWorkerThread threaderinProgress = (CustomWorkerThread)requestQueue.elementAt(i);
            threaderinProgress.stop = true;
            threaderinProgress = null;
        }
        _stop = true;
        requestQueue.removeAllElements();
    }

}
```

}

Custom Worker Thread class

```
public class CustomWorkerThread implements Runnable{

    public String url;
    private boolean _stop;
    HttpConnection connection;
    ImageDownloadListener listener;
    public boolean stop = false;

    CustomWorkerThread(String _url, ImageDownloadListener _listener){
        System.out.println("On Creating CustomWorkerThread >>>>>>>>"+_url);
        url = _url ;
        listener = _listener;
    }

    public byte[] getBytesData(){
        try{
            MyConnectionFactory _factory = new MyConnectionFactory();
            ConnectionDescriptor con=_factory.getConnection(url); 
            connection=(HttpConnection) con.getConnection();
            System.out.println("connectionUrl:"+connection.getURL());
            byte [] _data=null;
            InputStream is=null;
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray=new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
            try {           
                int rc = connection.getResponseCode();
                if(rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {          
                    is =  connection.openInputStream();
                    _data = new byte[10240*5];
                    int bytesRead=0;
                    while ((bytesRead = is.read(_data))!= -1){
                        byteArray.write(_data,0,bytesRead);
                    }
                    byte[] bData=byteArray.toByteArray();                    
                    return bData;

                }
            }catch (IOException e1) {
                System.out.println("Exception in Reading Data"+e1);
                stop = true;
            }finally {
                try {
                      if (is != null) is.close();        
                      if (connection != null) connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        stop = true;
                    }
           }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in getting Server Data"+e);
            stop = true;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void run(){
        if(stop)
            return;
        byte[] image = this.getBytesData();
        listener.imageDownloaded(image);
        System.out.println("Response Recieved From :>>>>>>>>"+url);
        this.stop();
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        stop = true;
        ImageDownloader.count--;
        ImageDownloader.requestinProgressQueue.removeElement(this);
        ImageDownloader.Reload();
        System.out.println("On Stop CustomWorkerThread >>>>>>>>"+url);
    }                       
}
```

Comment: Please show us your **code**.  This description isn't enough to tell you what's wrong.  Also, you can't start *"a new main thread"*.  There is one "main" thread, and BlackBerry starts that for you.  All the threads you create are worker threads.  Please update your description, as this is rather confusing.  Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense to me.  You declare `requestQueue` in the `ImageLoader` class, but then you use it in the `ImageDownloader` class.  How is this?  Is `ImageDownloader` an *inner class*?  You really need to format this code, as it's unreadable.  [Try this site](http://www.prettyprinter.de/module.php?name=PrettyPrinter).  This code has many, many problems.  I think it's going to be difficult for you to get help with this, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: requestQueue in ImageLoader class is not used at all,it is simply there not used at all.Let me Clean the code and update you,

Comment: @flav Your link discusses Java features that are not available on BlackBerry Java devices.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `ImageDownloader.stop()` until you are exiting the application. This will keep the `run` method running/waiting.